# pause terminal in between cat of multiple files

Tags: terminal, cat

In order to view multiple files in the terminal I would like the terminal to stop in between files. Using `cat folder/subfolder/*.file` is incredibly inconvenient with a lot of files.

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```
for i in `ls folder/subfolder/*.file`; do cat $i; read; done
```

You can also box it as a bash script.